# Killing a surfaceview

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, bitmap

I have a surfaceview with huge amount of bitmaps, mediaplayers, soundpools and objects. Is there a way to just unload everything from the memory and going back to the first activity, like a restart to the app?

Doing it manually and recycling each bitmap, releasing mediaplayer, and nulling objects sounds like a lot of work, there needs to be some way to restart the app and unload everything the app placed in the memory without causing a memory leak.

I tried using finish(); but that only closes the activity, it doesn't unload stuff like mediaplayer, and bitmap so it can cause a memory leak, and it also doesnt stop the surfaceview.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was simply writing `System.exit(0);`, this just closed the surfaceview and went back to the MainActivity, it also stopped the mediaplayers and cleaned everything from the memory. I'm not sure if its the best solution or if you should use it, but it seem to do the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run the class that extends SurfaceView in a thread. See this
http://https417.blogspot.com/2012/08/threading-surfaceview-in-android.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUmId0rwsBQ

Comment: I was thinking something like Calling the OnDestroy() method of thread from OnDestroy() method of activity and releasing mediaplayer in OnDestroy() method of thread.

Comment: thats manually doing it, I dont want that, I found a way to do it with one command, ill post the answer soon.